# how to choose between two extension methods for different types but in ambigouos call?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have various extension methods for the ICollection type. One of these is this:

```
public static void Insert<T>(this ICollection<T> paramColeccion, int paramPosicion, ICollection<T> paramElementos)
```

And I have various extension methods for ObservableCollection, one of these is this:

```
public static void Insert<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> paramColeccion, int paramPosicion, IEnumerable<T> paramElementos)
```

I am trying to use in this way:

```
myObservableCollection.insert(0, myListWithElements);
```

In one class, I need to have available the extension methods for both, ICollection and ObservableCollection, but when I am trying to use the extension method Insert of the ObservableCollection I get an error because it is an ambigous call.

For the ObservableCollection, I could use the extension method from ICollection, but if I do that it is not rised the CollectionChanged event, that I need, it is why I need to use method from ObservableCollection.

Thanks.

Comment: as far as i know, there is no way to circumvent this.. all we could do is calling them as static method.. although if they're in the same namespace we need to [alias them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144124/c-use-a-namespace-for-a-specific-block-of-code)..

Comment: Thanks, that's work.